# Fieldset as detailCard of a NestedList item

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a nested list on when i select a leaf I want to show a field set for some data entry.

so far i have;

```
launch: function () {
    Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
        fullscreen: true,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'nestedlist',
                title: 'Train Lines',
                iconCls: 'star',
                displayField: 'text',
                store:treeStore,
                detailCard: {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    scrollable: true,
                    styleHtmlContent: true
                },
                listeners: {
                    itemtap: function (nestedList, list, index, element, post) {
                        this.getDetailCard().setHtml(post.get('text'));
                    }
                }
            },
```

and as my fieldset i have

```
var fieldSet = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            fullscreen: true,
            items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'About You',
            instructions: 'Tell us all about yourself',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'firstName',
                    label: 'First Name'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'lastName',
                    label: 'Last Name'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

How do i replace the current detailCard with the contwents of the fieldset?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. Do you want the `fieldset` to be your `detailCard` for every leaf node? If so, why not just set `fieldSet` to be your `detailCard`? Otherwise, the `setDetailCard` method might be the way to go.